# using ! character in echo

Tags: bash, echo, special-characters

I am messing with echo and having issues with echo displaying the ! character.

I tried this.

```
echo -e "Wake!\nUp!
bash: !\n!: event not found
```

Then this

```
# echo "Wake\!\nUp!"
Wake\!
Up!
```

Well now the backslash AND the exclamation mark shows. How can I use this character properly? What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes:

```
$ echo -e 'Wake!\nUp!'
Wake!
Up!
```

If you use single quotes (`''`) shell will treat the string literally, whereas if you use double quotes (`""`) it will treat `!` as a reference to the previous command (event).

Comment: I figured using ( ' ' ) would take the ( \ ) literally also. I guess the -e takes care of taking escape sequences literally.

Comment: @AcousticBruce: You can think of this as two steps..at first we have escaped the shell by using single quotes, by doing this we have solved the problem regarding `!`.. as we got the string intact `Wake!\nUp!`, it is passed to `echo` ..again we need to get a new line by `\n` ..to do so we need the `-e` option of `echo` so that it will enable back slash escapes and we will get the new line...